# send NULL to sql field from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

my problem is when i send null from angularJS/javascript to my c# controller to declare one of my field as null , field is clear but not null how can i set field as null from javascript

```
$scope.formData.currentTempDocument = null

return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: rootURL + '/data/getdata',
    data: inputjsondata,
    dataType: 'text',
    processData: false,
    async: false,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    return response.data.EntityData;
});
```

Comment: How do you send your field from JS to c#?

Comment: use string constant. for eg. null is used in c# and NULL is used in javascript so you need to do conversion from each null in their respective language.

Comment: $http request  from an angular service

Comment: Could you please show the $http post?

Comment: @zps215 can you show me a sample

Comment: return $http({ method: 'POST', url: rootURL + '/data/getdata', data: inputjsondata, dataType: 'text', processData: false, async: false, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' } })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data.EntityData;
                });

Comment: @zps215 Yes, this could work, but then how do you distinguish `"null"` from `null`?

Comment: up there it s my getdata request setdata its like that

Comment: Please show what `inputjsondata` looks like before you submit it.

Comment: its very large why you want to see it?

Comment: @Pooria.Shariatzadeh you can use encoding technique like base64 encoding. encode in js and decode in c#. this way you can preserve the characters.

Comment: @Pooria.Shariatzadeh, can you provide declaration `getdata` action?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to deal with absence of your field from the JSON you submit. If the field is not there, it must be `NULL`! If the field is there, take the value from your request and process it. That should do it.

The controller is your backend and processes your request. So you should provide the logic in your controller to recognize that if the value is absent in the JSON you send to your controller, you want it to be `null` in the database. You could create your own protocol that states whenever a field is absent in the JSON from the client it must be `null` in the database.

Comment: my problem is i want to update that field not insert a record so my field have value i just want to update it to null

Comment: Added an explanation. Please check it out